# Why background-clip: content-box doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

In the given code ***background-clip: padding-box;*** is working but the ***background-clip: content-box;*** isn't working. Please tell me what is wrong here. I found that **padding** must be there for the background-clip property to work and I have added the padding as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .temp {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 153, 141);
        background-clip: content-box;
        border: 9px dotted blue;
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        /* background-clip: padding-box; */

    }

    .temp h3 {
        padding-top: 90px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="temp">
        <h3>Hasnain</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="temp">
        <h3>Zain</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="temp">
        <h3>brothers</h3>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like it's working to me. What are you expecting? Also there is no padding in your code. You can't clip to something that isn't there.

Comment: Since you have no padding, `content-box` and `padding-box` are the same.

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added the padding now.

Comment: @Kosh I have added the padding now.

Comment: @Hasnain, no you haven't. Add it to `.temp` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, you just added the padding to the wrong element ".temp h3" instead of ".temp"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .temp {
        width: 400px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 153, 141);
        background-clip: content-box;
        border: 9px dotted blue;
        margin: 20px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        /* background-clip: padding-box; */

    }

    .temp {
        padding-top: 90px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="temp">
        <h3>Hasnain</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="temp">
        <h3>Zain</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="temp">
        <h3>brothers</h3>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.